# Duplicate view using for loop in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating an application that allows for comments to be posted. I now need to duplicate a view based on how many comments there are. I have my ViewController with a separate view inside that which has the comment. The mini view is called commentView. I now want to duplicate that view based on how many comments there are, i.e. if there are 7 comments I need 7 of those views. I am unsure on how to go about it?

I have a basic for loop that just loops round based on the number of comments:

```
for (int i=0; i<totalCommentsNumber; i++) {
     NSLog(@"Testing %@", [commentArray objectAtIndex:i]); 
}
```

I've read that some people that have the same problem are suggesting to use table views?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, use Table Views. This brings in a great efficiency boost, as if you have 500 comments, instead of creating 500 cells, it creates as many cells that can fit on the visible screen, and when you scroll it reuses a cell that is now offscreen, preventing around ~485 allocations.

Comment: WDUK is correct, make use of UITableView

Comment: https://github.com/runmad/RMSwipeTableViewCell/

Comment: Sounds like the perfect use case for a UITableView with custom cells.